# Add suffix to filename if file already exist instead of overwriting it

Tags: java, file-io, overwrite

I'm saving an uploaded file as below:

```
UploadItem item = event.getUploadItem();
File dir = new File("D:/FileUpload");
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdir();
}
File bfile = new File("D:/FileUpload" + "/" + item.getFileName());
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);
outStream.write(item.getData());
outStream.close();
```

But my question is when upload once file same old file in folder **D:/FileUpload**. In above function it will delete old file. Example first time, i upload file : **test.doc** (old file). Then i upload another file with same name : **test.doc** (new file). At folder FileUpload will has one file is **test.doc** (new file). I want function will process similar in window OS is : new file will be **test (2).doc**. How can i process it ? And all cases : **D:/FileUpload** have many file : *test.doc*, *test (1).doc*, *test (2).doc*, *test (a).doc*,...... I think we just check with format **....(int).doc**. That new file will be :
**test (3).doc** (ignore *test(a).doc*)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this?  I list the files in your directory, compare the names of each to the name of your file.  If the names match, increment a count.  Then, when you come to create your file, include the count in its name.

```
UploadItem item = event.getUploadItem();
File dir = new File("D:/FileUpload");
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdir();
}
String [] files = dir.list();
int count = 0;

for(String file : files) {
  if (file.startsWith(item.getFileName()) {
    count++;
  }
}

File bfile = new File("D:/FileUpload" + "/" + item.getFileName() + "(" + count + ")");
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);
outStream.write(item.getData());
outStream.close();
```